# What color blending algorithm does MyPaint use?

Tags: colors, blending

I am confused with how does MyPaint blend color, here are what I did:

1. It has a background layer (initial white color).
2. Select a brush with some color and alpha < 1, paint some lines on the canvas.
3. When I paint at the same line, it will be deepen.
4. Change the background layer to any color or image, the line still look nice.

So, my questions are:

1. How does it blend color when I paint at the same place with alpha < 1?
2. How does it blend color between canvas and background layer?

Thanks.

Comment: MyPaint is open source, have you looked at the source code?

Comment: Welcome to [so], please read the [FAQ]'s, [ask] and hang around for a bit after asking a question here as this is a very active site. Good luck!

Comment: RE @Rotem: Sorry, I am a newbie to programming and I don't familiar with python.